# Multitasking multiple Class Instances

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, multitasking

Today I decided to try out multi-Tasking to see if I get a performance improvement compared to multi-Threading. Im especially interested because Im looking for an easy way to return values and and use features like WaitAll or WaitAny. My question is what am I doing wrong and what is the best way to multitask multiple Instances?

Here is my old code using Threads. (Working)

```
Thread[] threads = new Thread[5];
ScrapeFollowersIds[] scrapeClass = new ScrapeFollowersIds[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  scrapeClass[i] = new ScrapeFollowersIds();
  threads[i] = new Thread(() => scrapeClass[i].ScrapeFollowers(cookie,proxy);
  threads[i].Start();
}
```

And here is my new solution.

Every Task shows me Status = Faulted, Method {null}, Result not yet computed
Looking at the exception I get Inner Exception: Index was outside the bounds of the Array

```
Task<string>[] scrapeFollowers = new Task<string>[5];
ScrapeFollowersIds[] scrapeClass = new ScrapeFollowersIds[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  scrapeClass[i] = new ScrapeFollowersIds();
  scrapeFollowers[i] = Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() => 
                         scrapeClass[i].ScrapeFollowers(cookie, proxy);
}
```

The method Im calling looks like this

```
try
{  
  //Dosomething 
  return someString;
} 
catch
{
  return "";
}
```

Comment: You are [closing over the loop variable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx), a classic mistake.

Comment: Please read the definition of *multi-tasking* vs. *multi-threading*. Wikipedia is a reasonable source of overall beginner information for such topics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're closing over the loop variable, `i`.

The bug actually exists in both programs.

Since the lambda defining the code to run in another thread closes over `i`, and `i` ends up being (potentially) changed by the main thread before the code actually runs.  Take a copy of the loop variable inside of the loop and close over *that*.

Having said that, you can avoid the entire situation entirely using the TPL by not creating an external array that all of the tasks need to manually access.  It's not a very TPL oriented way of doing things.  Instead have each task independently create its result, and then aggregate the results:

```
var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 5)
    .Select(_ => Task.Run(() => CreateScrapeFollower(cookie, proxy)));

var results = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: But can I return a string value like that?

Comment: @user3155276 Sure.  The results will all be in the `results` variable.

Comment: Im still a bit confused. Does this create 5 different instances of the Class? Because I want to use 5 tasks with 5 instances of the class.

Comment: @user3155276 Presumably the `CreateScrapeFollower` method would create an instance of the class and then use it.